# Eclipse Package/Project Explorer Filters: Show dirty files

Tags: eclipse, force-ide

Is there a way to filter files in Eclipse's Project/Package Explorer views based on the state of a file according to Git (or SVN)? Ideally, I'd only like to see files that are marked dirty, select, and right-click on them as a group so I can access this context menu.

[image]

Eclipse has a "Git Staging" view which gives me the same list. But right-clicking on the files from this view gives a different context menu that I don't want:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you want?

Comment: Operations like 'Team > Commit' just work on the dirty files automatically.

Comment: @nitind I need to multi-select the dirty files in my project. In Eclipse, you multi-select from the Project Explorer by doing `CTRL + left mouse click` for every individual file. I do this so I can right click on the selected files and access functions/operations from the context-menu. I was wondering if I can just filter the files in my project explorer view based on their dirty state, instead of individually selecting them which can be inconvenient sometimes.

Comment: @greg-449 I need to access and run operations that are only available from the Project/Package Explorer views in Eclipse (first screenshot)